# Google colab CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device

Tags: google-colaboratory

when I run my code on colab gpu today, I got A100-SXM4-40GB and an error which is 'CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device'. I ran the exactly same code on colab gpu last week, there was no such error. I also try to run my code on cpu, it has no issue. Could you please let me know what happens? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Please see https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2287 for a workaround (and subscribe to notified of eventual resolution).